# Get-PhysicalDisk Sorting Number as text

Tags: powershell

When I get results of `Get-PhysicalDisk` it appears that results are sorted as text and not as number:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk   | Where-Object { $_.CanPool -eq $True } |  Sort-Object -Property DeviceID
```

I get

```
Number  OperationalStatus   HealthStatus
10  SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
11  SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
12  SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
13  SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
14  SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
15  SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
16  SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
17  SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
18  SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
19  SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
20  SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
5   SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
6   SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
7   SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
8   SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
9   SSD TRUE    OK  Healthy Auto-Select 6.82    TB
```

So It appears that the sort is in the Text Order and not the number. How Do I order it as a number ?

Answer (score 2):

[`.DeviceId` is a string property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/stormgmt/msft-physicaldisk#syntax) so you would need to cast `[int]` using a [calculated expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3#sort-object) to sort them properly:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true | Sort-Object { [int] $_.DeviceId }
```